# Run cmd from vbscript silently

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I created the following runas.vbs script:

```
**************
Option explicit

Dim oShell, k

Const PASSWORD = "Pass123~"

set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.Sleep 500

oShell.run("RunAs /noprofile /user:%computername%\postgres " & Chr(34) & "cmd /c\" & 

Chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(0) & "\" & Chr(34) & Chr(34))

WScript.Sleep 1000

For k=1 To Len(PASSWORD)

  WScript.Sleep 200

  oShell.SendKeys Mid(PASSWORD,k,1)

Next

Wscript.Quit

**************
```

I use this vbscript in a Batch file to run initdb.exe (Postgresql).
Used as:

```
cscript //Nologo //B runasNSPostgres.vbs ""%LG_PATH%\initdb.exe" --locale=C --encoding=UTF-8  -U %DBADMIN% -D "%DBDATA%""
```

When this command is executed, another command prompt screen opens up which starts the initdb processing. I do not want the new cmd prompt screen to show up. I want the initdb.exe to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide the command prompt window, you won't be able to use `SendKeys` to send it your password keystrokes.

You can use another method, though. Try using the `ECHO` command and pipe its output to `RunAs`.

```
oShell.Run "echo " & PASSWORD & " | runas /noprofile ...", 0
```

Use a `0` as the 2nd parameter to prevent the window from appearing.

Comment: When I use this command, nothing happens......---- oShell.Run "echo " & PASSWORD & " | runas /noprofile ...", 0 -----

Comment: The `...` was just a placeholder for the rest of your command. Make sure you include your whole command line.

Comment: Yes.. This is what I used but nothing happened -- oShell.run "echo " & PASSWORD & " | RunAs /noprofile /user:%computername%\postgres " & Chr(34) & "cmd /c\" & Chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(0) & "\" & Chr(34) & Chr(34),0 -- The pipe is supposed to be inside the qoutes or outside?

Comment: This might be a dead end. I tried it with `CMD /A` and `CMD /U` but it doesn't look like `runas` properly accepts the standard input as a password string, which is interesting because it does complete the password prompt.

Comment: so is there any alternate way to accomplish the same task?

Comment: A one-time scheduled task? You can supply command-line credentials when creating a task (username/password) and the task will run as that user. See the `SCHTASKS` command.